# NaN returned when converting string to number within a for loop

Tags: regex, matlab, for-loop, cell-array

```
for n=1:37
    for m=2:71
        rep1 = regexp(Cell1{n,m}, 'f[0-9]*', 'match')
        rep2 = regexp(rep1, '[0-9]*', 'match')
        rep2 = [rep2{:}]
        cln = str2double(rep2)
        Cell2{n,cln} = Cell1{n,m}
    end
end
```

Cell 1 is a 37x71 Cell, Cell 2 is a 37x71 empty cell.

Ex

```
 Cell1{1,2} = -(f32.*x1.*x6)./v1
```

If I run each part of the loop above individually, the function works as intended.  However, it returns `cln` as a NaN when the whole loop is executed.

Comment: What is a `NaN error`? There is no such thing in MATLAB

Comment: The error is that the variable cln is returned as a Nan

Comment: Thats because, for some reason `rep2` is not a numeric string.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a NaN because your regex doesn't match one of the values of `Cell1` and returns an empty string (which `str2double` converts to a NaN).

But let's take a step back for a second here. You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) on cell arrays so there is no need to loop through all of your elements. Also, you can use a [look behind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to look for that "f" that precedes your number therefore preventing the use of `regexp` twice.

```
stringNumber = regexp(Cell1, '(?<=f)[0-9]*', 'match', 'once');
numbers = str2double(stringNumber);
```

You can then check for NaNs (`isnan(numbers)`) and look closer at the elements of `Cell1` to see why your regex isn't finding a number in a particular string.

Once you get that sorted out, you can assign to `Cell2` like you are doing

```
Cell2 = cell(37, 71);
for k = 1:numel(numbers)
    row = mod(k - 1, size(Cell1, 2)) + 1;
    Cell2(row, numbers(k)) = Cell1(k);
end
```